# How to merge two forms into one?

Tags: html, css

I want to have these two buttons in one line, so `Remove` button is in the position in which it is and the `Update mapping` button is on the right.
So it would looks like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: As i told in one of comments, remove css from form elements. Instead use background and padding css on "div". Forms can be inline-blocks etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add style "display : inline-block" to your forms.

```html
<div>
            <form style="display: inline-block" action="/.../delete" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="name1" th:value="${tmpl.variable1} + '_' + ${tmpl.variable2}"
                        class="secondary">Remove
                </button>
            </form>
            <form style="display: inline-block" action="/.../update" method="get">
                <button type="submit" name="name2" th:value="${tmpl.variable1} + '_' + ${tmpl.variable2}"
                        class="button primary">Update mapping
                </button>
            </form>
            <pre th:utext="${tmpl.response}"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: ye, it works, but now there is no long grey line. Check my edit.

Comment: You just remove your background gray on your forms and then you can use background gray on your dev. Ex. <div class="long-bg-gray">
            <form style="display: inline-block" action="/.../delete" method="post">
                 ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="display: inline-flex"` at parent div.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="collapse">
<th:block th:each="tmpl,iterStat : ${templates}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:id="'collapse-section' + ${iterStat.count}" aria-hidden="true"/>
    <label th:for="'collapse-section' + ${iterStat.count}" aria-hidden="true"><span ....></label>
    <div style="display: inline-flex">
        <form action="/.../delete" method="post" style="float: left; width 40%">
            <button type="submit" name="name1" th:value="${tmpl.variable1} + '_' + ${tmpl.variable2}"
                    class="secondary">Remove
            </button>
        </form>
        <div style="width: 20%"></div>
        <form action="/.../update" method="get" style="width: 40%">
            <button type="submit" name="name2" th:value="${tmpl.variable1} + '_' + ${tmpl.variable2}"
                    class="button primary">Update mapping
            </button>
        </form>
        <pre th:utext="${tmpl.response}"/>
    </div>
</th:block>
```

Comment: it is not what I wanted. It looks worse. I want to have on this one grey line two buttons. Not two seperate grey lines. I have edited question to show you how it looks now.

Comment: @pqa1222 as far as i understan. You have gray background and paddings on form elements. Remove this css. Instead use it on div element, which is parent for both forms

Comment: @pqa1222 I've updated my answer. This is a workaround if you do not wish to use bootstrap's grid system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use floats for forms or `display:flex` on forms parent.

```css
div {display:flex;}
```

```html
        <div>
            <form action="/.../delete" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="name1" th:value="${tmpl.variable1} + '_' + ${tmpl.variable2}"
                        class="secondary">Remove
                </button>
            </form>
            <form action="/.../update" method="get">
                <button type="submit" name="name2" th:value="${tmpl.variable1} + '_' + ${tmpl.variable2}"
                        class="button primary">Update mapping
                </button>
            </form>
            <pre th:utext="${tmpl.response}"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: what is forms parent?

Comment: @pqa1222 in this case "div", cause forms are wrapped in it.

Comment: All right. So I have created id for div and move all styles to div in css. And it works, yes, but there is one problem. https://zapodaj.net/71e4a10ec3539.png.html I have some kind of response in the same div and it appears on the right. I would like to have this on the bottom of the buttons like I had before. Is it possible?

Comment: @pqa1222 make it in css width 100% or instead don't use "display:flex" on div, but use "display:inline-block" on forms

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootstrap's grid system:

```
<html>
....
<div class="collapse">
    <th:block th:each="tmpl,iterStat : ${templates}">
        ...
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <form action="/.../delete" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="name1" th:value="${tmpl.variable1} + '_' + ${tmpl.variable2}"
                        class="secondary">Remove
                </button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <form action="/.../update" method="get">
                <button type="submit" name="name2" th:value="${tmpl.variable1} + '_' + ${tmpl.variable2}"
                        class="button primary">Update mapping
                </button>
            </form>
          </div>
            <pre th:utext="${tmpl.response}"/>
        </div>
    </th:block>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you can set the width of columns changing the `col` class. Here's the guide: [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: overkill to load whole bootstrap css files just to do simple float. + in this case for forms is needed dynamic width not defined